# React Navigation V6 large header option with blur effect doesn't work if my app is in dark mode but the phone is in light mode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have the following styling to a NativeStackNavigationOption

```
navigationOptions = (): NativeStackNavigationOptions => ({
    ...LargeHeaderOptions,
    title: "Search Screen", 
})
```

The styling is:

```
LargeHeaderOptions: NativeStackNavigationOptions = {
headerLargeTitle: true,
headerShadowVisible: true,
headerLargeStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
},
headerBlurEffect: 'regular',
headerTransparent: Platform.OS === 'ios',
headerTitleStyle: {
    fontSize: getScaledFontSize(18, NAVIGATION_BAR_MAX_SCALE)
}
}
```

My problem is that when my app is in dark mode but the phone is in light mode, the blur effect that I get is still light. I tried changing the `headerBlurEffect` to other values from the documentation to make sure that it is working so that I can conditionally change it depending on my theme but no matter what value I set there, it seems to render a light mode blur effect but if the phone is in dark mode it renders a dark mode blur effect.